# MongoDB indexes no usage despite query on them?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

This is my pipeline:

```
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
        {
            {"$sort", bson.D{{"created_at", -1}}}, 
        },
        {
            {"$group", bson.D{
                {"_id", "$uid"},
                {"latest_job", bson.D{{"$first", "$$ROOT"}}},
            }},
        },
        {
            {"$replaceRoot", bson.D{{"newRoot", "$latest_job"}}},
        },
        {
            {"$limit", 20},
        },
    }
```

This is my indexes:

[image]

Clearly there are no indexes usage on created_at and uid. This query runs every second so I expect more usage on that. Why?

Comment: The comment next to the sort stage doesn't seem to align with what is specified, which is correct? Also, what does the explain plan for the aggregation show?